# Plot function is showing a wrong result

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I'm trying to plot this function, but probably since the numbers are really small it shows a fake plot in log log scale. Is there a way to solve this problem?

```
LogLogPlot[499*(6000 - x)^498/6000^499, {x, 1, 9000}, 
 PlotRange -> {{1, 7000}, Automatic}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, 
 Ticks -> {{10, 100, 1000, 6000}, Automatic}]
```

The hump near 6000 doesn't exist

Comment: Try: LogLogPlot[N@499*(6000 - x)^498/6000^499, {x, 1, 9000}, 
 PlotRange -> {{1, 7000}, Automatic}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, 
 Ticks -> {{10, 100, 1000, 6000}, Automatic}]

Comment: For me it's the same

Comment: You need to use `PlotRange -> {{1, 7000}, All}` to show the full range of values. To prevent it from showing any errors, you can use `PlotRange->{{1, 7000}, {10^-1000, 1}}` (otherwise, it tries to plot `0` at `x=6000` which will obviously not work)

Comment: Even with your solution it doesn't work.. probably it's not just the final number but the intermediate results.

Comment: @davideor You'll have to be more specific than "does not work", for me, the following plot is produced with `LogLogPlot[499*(6000 - x)^498/6000^499, {x, 1, 9000}, 
 PlotRange -> {{1, 7000}, {10^-1000, 1}}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, 
 Ticks -> {{10, 100, 1000, 6000}, Automatic}]`: [Image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/omRvm.png)

Comment: my output is not the same, i still see the said artificial hump https://imgur.com/a/Z05znyt

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like the problem is that your plot simply doesn't go far enough. For a plot like that, I would go at least to 2 * your multiplier (6000), so I would go to 12000 at least on the x-axis.

I've also gone to smaller y-values to better visualize the dip.

```
LogLogPlot[
  499*(6000 - x)^498/6000^499, 
  {x, 1, 12000}, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, 
  Ticks -> {
    {10, 100, 1000, 6000}, 
    Table[
      {10^i, Superscript["10", ToString[i]], {0.01, 0}}, 
      {i, -2000, 0, 200}
    ]
  }
]
```

[image: LogLogPlot of poster's function with expanded x-scale.]

Comment: I still have an output different from yours..  https://imgur.com/a/Z05znyt

Comment: @davideor If you use the code I posted above in a fresh kernel, you should get the same output unless it's a weird version-dependent thing. Perhaps you have some kind of lingering definitions that are not the same as what the rest of us are using, because none of us seem to be able to replicate what you're seeing. Try starting from a fresh kernel and see if that helps.

Comment: The fact that in our lab we are using Wolfram mathematica 10 could be relevant?

Comment: @davideor Possibly? You might want to add your version details and OS to the post and see if anyone running the same version/OS can replicate it. I only have version 12 on macOS 10.15.1. Though I have to admit, I would be pretty surprised to find that MMA v10 behaved that differently on such a simple plot.